# Cannot Install Python NumPy Module on Mac Despite Scouring The Known Internet

Tags: python, numpy

All - Despite my best efforts, random internet posts and seemingly related Stack Overflow threads, I have been unable to successfully install NumPy on my Mac (OS Mountain Lion).

From various sources, my understanding is that I must install XCode and the developer command line tools, both of which I have done.  However, as per the terminal print-out below, something still isn't right.

If someone could point me in the right direction, and perhaps also explain why it is so difficult to install Python modules in the first place (I am also having issues with scikit-learn), I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you very much.

Terminal Print-Out:

Last login: Tue Jul  2 21:32:39 on ttys000
amormachines-macbook:~ amormachine$ pip install numpy
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.
    non-existing path in '/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
      FOUND:
        extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
        extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']

```
lapack_opt_info:
  FOUND:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']

build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize NAGFCompiler
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
customize IBMFCompiler
Could not locate executable xlf90
Could not locate executable xlf
customize IntelFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize PGroupFCompiler
Could not locate executable pgfortran
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
C compiler: gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3

compile options: '-I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/private -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/npymath -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/multiarray -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/umath -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/npysort -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c'
gcc-4.0: _configtest.c
sh: gcc-4.0: command not found
sh: gcc-4.0: command not found
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/setup.py", line 214, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/setup.py", line 207, in setup_package
    configuration=configuration )
  File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 186, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 8, in run
    self.run_command("build_src")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 152, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 163, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 298, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 385, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/setup.py", line 648, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Running from numpy source directory.
```

non-existing path in '/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

FOUND:

```
extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']

define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]

extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
```

lapack_opt_info:

FOUND:

```
extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']

define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]

extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
```

running egg_info

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

building library "npymath" sources

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Could not locate executable gfortran

Could not locate executable f95

customize NAGFCompiler

customize AbsoftFCompiler

Could not locate executable f90

Could not locate executable f77

customize IBMFCompiler

Could not locate executable xlf90

Could not locate executable xlf

customize IntelFCompiler

Could not locate executable ifort

Could not locate executable ifc

customize GnuFCompiler

Could not locate executable g77

customize G95FCompiler

Could not locate executable g95

customize PGroupFCompiler

Could not locate executable pgfortran

don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'

C compiler: gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3

compile options: '-I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/private -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/npymath -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/multiarray -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/umath -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/src/npysort -I/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c'

gcc-4.0: _configtest.c

sh: gcc-4.0: command not found

sh: gcc-4.0: command not found

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 16, in

File "/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/setup.py", line 214, in

```
setup_package()
```

File "/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/setup.py", line 207, in setup_package

```
configuration=configuration )
```

File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 186, in setup

```
return old_setup(**new_attr)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

```
dist.run_commands()
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

```
self.run_command(cmd)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

```
cmd_obj.run()
```

File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 8, in run

```
self.run_command("build_src")
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

```
self.distribution.run_command(command)
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

```
cmd_obj.run()
```

File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 152, in run

```
self.build_sources()
```

File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 163, in build_sources

```
self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
```

File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 298, in build_library_sources

```
sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
```

File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 385, in generate_sources

```
source = func(extension, build_dir)
```

File "/private/var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy/numpy/core/setup.py", line 648, in get_mathlib_info

```
raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
```

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

---

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/wk/r5j_bvnd28bd2ff42jctw8n80000gn/T/pip-build/numpy
Storing complete log in /Users/amormachine/.pip/pip.log
amormachines-macbook:~ amormachine$

Comment: Have you tried using macports?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your command line tools are not properly installed.  Are you using the python version that ships with Mac?  This is generally not recommended anyway, I would nuke your pip and python installations, make sure the command line tools are solid and start from scratch.  Not the best answer I know but pip should work fine

Comment: Or check out Continuum's Anaconda or the Enthought Python distribution. Both free and both have one-click installers that will install a clean version of python with most of the scientific stack outside of your system python.

Comment: Yes - I am using the Python distribution that comes with the Mac.  Can you clarify how to fully remove pip / python and verify the command line tools?

As for Enthought, I have that as well.  If I run a program from within Canopy Enthought, I can import numpy.  Oddly though, if I run iPython from the terminal, I cannot.

Comment: Downloading Anaconda for Python ultimately fixed everything.